# How to simplify Nest.js controller implementation with JWT support

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm creating controller which is protected by JWTAuthGuard.
Is there any way to make the controller smaller? (decorators, interceptors etc).

My current code:

```
import {User} from "../../user/entities/user.entity";

interface UserJwtPayload {
    user: {
        id: number,
        email: string
    },
}

class CreateDeviceLocationDto {
    lat: number
    long: number
    description: string
    user: User
}


@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
@Controller('device-locations')
export class DeviceLocationsController {
    constructor(private readonly userService: UserService, private readonly deviceLocationsService: DeviceLocationsService) {
    }

    @Post()
    async create(@Body() createDeviceLocationDto: CreateDeviceLocationDto, @Req() request: Request & UserJwtPayload) {
        const user: User = await this.userService.findOne(request.user.id);

        createDeviceLocationDto.user = user;

        return this.deviceLocationsService.create(createDeviceLocationDto);
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class DeviceLocationsService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(DeviceLocation)
        private readonly devicesLocationRepository: Repository<DeviceLocation>
    ) {
    }

    create(createDeviceLocationDto: CreateDeviceLocationDto) {
        const location = this.devicesLocationRepository.create(createDeviceLocationDto);
        return this.devicesLocationRepository.save(location);
    }
}
```

1. It is annoying to add `@Req() request: Request & UserJwtPayload` in every method.
2. Is there any way to save model to database (I user TypeORM) without loading the user every time?
   (`const user: User = await this.userService.findOne(request.user.id);`)? I need to pass user id only which is already available from JWT token.

Thanks!

The above code works. I just want to simplify it, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sooo... (I might have skipped some imports for brevity, hope that's fine).

**First of all:**

Inject the request to the controller constructor - to make it globally available to controller methods, without using parameter decorators:

```js
import { Controller, Get, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core';
import type { Request } from 'express';


@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
@Controller()
export class DeviceLocationsController {
  constructor(@Inject(REQUEST) private request: Request) {}
}
```

More on that: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes#request-provider

**Second of all - which version of NestJS do you use?**

Afaik, in Nest 10, `express.Request` has `user` definition out-of-the box. Just remember to import this type from `express`.

If you don't have `user` there, define it in a `d.ts` file (eg `src/request.d.ts`):

```
export {}

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
      user?: IUserInRequest;
    }
  }
}
```

**Third of all:**

If we talk about simplicity and cleaner code, this part:

```js
const user: User = await this.userService.findOne(request.user.id);
createDeviceLocationDto.user = user;
return this.deviceLocationsService.create(createDeviceLocationDto);
```

can be easily changed to:

```js
return this.deviceLocationService.create(createDeviceLocationDto, user);
```

where `deviceLocationService` has a binding for service that can resolve user. **But!** Does it really need to have full user, or maybe just user's identifier?

Remember that in order to get a JWT token, user must be found in the database, so whenever JWT token is valid, it means the user was allowed to receive that token, and there's no need to refetch their data. That's the whole idea of JWT tokens - to limit number of DB calls to absolute minimum.

If other user properties beside default stored in request are needed, then just make them available in the `request.user` by updating `canActivate` method in `JwtAuthGuard` to something like:

```js
const userInPayload = await this.jwtService.verifyAsync(token, {
    secret: 'wlazlkoteknaplotek',
});

const userData  = await this.userService.findOneOrThrow(userInPayload);

// id: 123, language: is-IS, etc.

request.user = payload; // to make language available in request.user
```

If you'll still hit the typing issues, extend Request in `d.ts` as specified above :)

---

**Extra comments :) **

1. Don't update your DTO in controller. Instead of that, pass DTO and other stuff to service separately. This will make the code (1) easier to debug, (2) better typed - you don't need to make separate types for DTO without user that is used by controller method, and DTO with user that is used by service.
2. Speaking of that, you have a type for DTO that includes `user: User`. This is wrong, because there is no `User` in the request body, so `create(@Body() createDeviceLocationDto: CreateDeviceLocationDto)` comes with a type-unsafety problem.
3. About storing user to database - there is absolutely **no** reason to pass full user info to the user repository. No matter if you use relational, or NoSQL database, you need user ID only. So that async call to database to find user only to pass the full user to another repository, where it will either way probably be reverted to user ID, it's an overkill for resources, and for the code organization :) That's all you need:

```
const { user } = this.request;
return this.deviceService.create(dto, user);
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. I understand how to do things properly, but have no experience with this stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Decorators`. Here's an example:

```
  @Get('cart')
  @UseGuards(JwtAuthenticationGuard)
  async getCart(@GetCurrentUser() user: UserWithRolesAndOrganizations) {
    return await this.ordersService.getCart({
      userId: user.id,
      organizationId: user.organizationId,
    });
  }
```

And for the `GetCurrentUser`, it'll look something like this:

```
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserWithRolesAndOrganizations } from '../../users-repository/types/user-roles-organization.type';

export const GetCurrentUser = createParamDecorator(
  (_: undefined, context: ExecutionContext): UserWithRolesAndOrganizations => {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const user = request.user;
    return user;
  },
);
```

But you can move your `request.user.id` to the guard.

Answer (score 0):

Ockham's razor. Don't multiply decorators over necessity :)

1. `@Req` is a decorator itself. There's no difference if you use `@Req` or custom decorator. Actually, using custom decorator here = more decorators, more code, more lines to debug and maintain.
2. `user` **is** in the request. So the goal is to find the way to get it from the request. You can use the `@Req`, but if you don't want to call it over and over again, custom decorator solves nothing. Number of decorators to be called - stays the same. Inject request in constructor :)